# Unable to map objects into React horizontal Menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a data object list which I am able to map into React horizontal menu.
But when I am trying to map another object to the menu I am unable to do so.

This data is in a little different format.
I want to map title of contents of first sections for example.
I have provided the data as well the code of the working code.

The ScrollMenu takes data to display here it is menu:

```js
<ScrollMenu
    arrowLeft={ArrowLeft}
    arrowRight={ArrowRight}
    data={menu}
    onSelect={this.onSelect}
    selected={selected}
/>
```

Here the menu is storing a value returned in `menuItems` and selected is any value from the array of values which you want to display, so here it should be doc1 instead of item1.

```
selected = "doc 1"
const menu = this.menuItems;
menuItems = Menu(data.sections[0].contents, this.state.selected)
```

So keeping everything same just instead of data.section[0] we use list works
[Sandbox Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-horizontal-scrolling-menu-forked-jvvl9?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

You are currently setting the default **key** of the **list** item as the **selected** state value instead of the title of the doc inside the **data** variable.

Try to specify keys for the list items manually.

```
let list = [
  { name: "item1", key: 1 },
  { name: "item2", key: 2 },
  { name: "item3", key: 3 },
  { name: "item4", key: 4 }
];
```

Use the current list item key to select an index inside the data.sections[0].contents array. This will return the docs' title, description and value. You can now set the content doc as the value of selected state.

```
onSelect = (key) => {
    console.log(`onSelect: ${key}`);
    this.setState({ selected: data.sections[0].contents[key].title });
  };
```